# Server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed. Parse to mLab migration

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mlab

I'm working on migrating my parse app to mLab but when I put my connection URL `mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds159747.mlab.com:59747/appname` in the parse migration tool it gives me this error:

```
Server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use the mongodb "User" and "Password" to connect mongodb:

MONGOLAB_URI: "mongodb://User:Password@mlab.com:12345/db"

Note : If you have not the "User" and "Password" for mongodb than you have to create first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using with dokku mongo:import . 
**In my case I included dot(period) in my db name**

You shouldn't include dot in your mongodb name when 'dokku mongo:create ' I've changed it to seunghunlee instead of seunghunlee.net now this command works

```
dokku mongo:import seunghunlee < seunghunlee.net.dump.gz
```

Hope it helps!